# How can i design a non static-path in my python script?

Tags: python, encryption, tkinter

**My application made with Tkinter uses the (path = 'c:/') variable to find the location of the file required to be encrypted. However, these locations might differ based on the user's preference. what is the best practice in this type of situation?**

```
path = "C:/Users/Documents/Coding Projects/The vault/Pics"

os.chdir("C:/Users/Documents/Coding Projects/The vault/Gui")
file = open('lvkey.key', 'rb')
key = file.read()
file.close()




def encrypt():
    dir = os.listdir(path)
    new_path = [path + '/' + i for i in dir]
    for i in new_path:
        with open(i, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()

        fernet = Fernet(key)
        encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)

        with open(i, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(encrypted)
```

Comment: Why not use tkFileDialog?

Comment: def encrypt() gets called after my user quits the application. How can I use FileDialog in this case?

Comment: If we are talking a command line execution have a look at argumentparser / optionparser. If we are talking storing the user preferred path into a config file / data file and remove it afterwards (or not) then you could store the user preferred path in such a file and use it in your encrypt function.